# Looking up values in a CRS sparse matrix?

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix

I am new to the use of sparse matrices, but now need to utilize one in my work to save space.  I understand that the following matrix:

```
10   0    0    0   -2    0
3    9    0    0    0    3
0    7    8    7    0    0
3    0    8    7    5    0
0    8    0    9    9    13
0    4    0    0    2   -1
```

can be represented with three vectors like this:

```
[10 -2 3 9 3 7 8 7 3 8 7 5 8 9 9 13 3 2 -1] // nonzero_vals

[1 5 1 2 6 2 3 4 1 3 4 5 2 4 5 6 2 5 6] // col_indices

[1 3 6 9 13 17 20] // row_ptr (indices of values that start row)
```

My problem is now determining the proper equations for value lookup in O(1) time.  If I, for example, want to return what matrix value is stored at location (2,2), how do I return 9?  Also, how do I return 0 if the lookup coordinates are not represented in the sparse matrix, also in O(1) time?

I appreciate any help you can provide.  I'm sure there are well established equations for this, but I am unable to find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *O(1)* procedure for obtaining the value at an arbitrary *(i,j)* coordinate (at least not without preprocessing). The best you can do is *O(log N)* on average (where the matrix is *MxN*), via a binary search procedure on the column indices.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* Well, really it's *O(log k)*, where *k* is the number of non-zeros in the row.  However, if one assumes that density is unrelated to matrix size (which is often the case), then *O(log N)* is valid.</sub>

Comment: What is the correct (quickest) process to do a lookup then?  (For a CSR matrix)

Comment: @user1764386: Well, you can get the relevant row_ptr values in constant time.  You then use these to bound a binary search on the col_indices array.